# Could not inspect the application package. Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain Code: -402653103

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile

I have this error installing app on simulator or physical device. I tried delete Derived data and clean folder but not work. Here's the detail log.
can someone help me?
Thank you!!!

```
Details

Unable to install "Mr3-dashboard"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000013935c3b8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000013939aae1 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d47ebac DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000013939a822 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x000000013904e999 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.294 + 3534
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d5b1921 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010d5b354b __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20283623 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20284806 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2028a5ea _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2028b0ad _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20294c0d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 811
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2042b45d _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2042a42f start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.6 (Build 20G165)
Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
Timestamp: 2021-10-12T17:08:01+08:00
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by deleting google-cast SDK. So I think this error occurs because of 3rd party SDK.